# rest of string into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an string that I explode by "/", getting something like this:

```
/*
["wf_event_name/events/1"]=>
  string(5) "test1"
  ["wf_event_description/events/1"]=>
  string(5) "test1"
  ["wf_event_name/events/1/1"]=>
  string(6) "test11"
  ["wf_event_description/events/1/1"]=>
  string(6) "test11"
  ["wf_event_name/events/2"]=>
  string(5) "test2"
  ["wf_event_description/events/2"]=>
  string(5) "test2"
*/
```

In every part every thing between "event" and next wf_event_ is the "order" of events.

What I would like is :

```
$events = array("event" => 1);
$events = array("event" => 1, "event" -> 1);
$events = array("event" => 2);
```

(the number of "events" is unknown - could be 0 or 100)
Any one?

EDIT: (tried this so far)

```
$_event_array = array();
foreach ($_POST AS $post => $value) {
    $pos = strpos($post, "wf_event_");
if ($pos !== false) {
    /* Split string into parts */
    /* 1.st post value name */
    /* event segmentation (any thing after this gives the placement in dependency) */
    /* event order (segmented by / ) */
        $_event_array[] = explode('/', $post);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? And why would you want to overwrite `$events` everytime?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, what is your aim ?

Comment: Is your expectation  correct ?

Comment: $events -> $events[] - no, it should not be overwritten.

Comment: Post your string where you were exploding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array();
$string = "wf_event_name/events/1";
$pos = str_replace("wf_event_name/", "", $string);
$array = explode('/',$pos);

$output[$array[0]]=$array[1];
print_r($output);
```